# How can I get a list of values for rows combined by groupby in a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 2, 1),
                   (1, 2, 2),
                   (1, 2, 3),
                   (4, 1, 612),
                   (4, 1, 612),
                   (4, 1, 1),
                   (3, 2, 1),
                   ],
                  columns=['groupid', 'a', 'b'],
                  index=['India', 'France', 'England', 'Germany', 'UK', 'USA',
                         'Indonesia'])
print(df)
```

which gives:

```
           groupid  a    b
India            1  2    1
France           1  2    2
England          1  2    3
Germany          4  1  612
UK               4  1  612
USA              4  1    1
Indonesia        3  2    1
```

### Step 1

This step might not be necessary / be different than how I imagine it. I'm actually only interested in Step 2, but having this helps me to think about it and explain what I want.

I want to group the data by groupid (`df.groupby(df['groupid'])`) and get something like this:

```
    groupid  a    b
          1  [2]  [1, 2, 3]
          4  [1]  [612, 1]
          3  [2]  [1]
```

### Step 2

Then I want to find all group IDs which have only one entry in column b and for which the entry is equal to `1`.

Similarly, I want to find all group IDs which have either multiple entries or one entry which is not `1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compare `set`s and then get values of index to `list`s:

```
mask = df.groupby('groupid')['b'].apply(set) == set([1])
print (mask)
groupid
1    False
3     True
4    False
Name: b, dtype: bool

i = mask.index[mask].tolist()
print (i)
[3]

j = mask.index[~mask].tolist()
print (j)
[1, 4]
```

For new column use `map`:

```
df['new'] = df['groupid'].map(df.groupby('groupid')['b'].apply(set) == set([1]))
print (df)

           groupid  a    b    new
India            1  2    1  False
France           1  2    2  False
England          1  2    3  False
Germany          4  1  612  False
UK               4  1  612  False
USA              4  1    1  False
Indonesia        3  2    1   True
```

old solution:

You can use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html) for new `Series` with same size as original df, so is possible compare it with `1` for uniqueness and then chain another condition for compare with `1`:

```
mask = (df.groupby('groupid')['b'].transform('nunique') == 1) & (df['b'] == 1)
print (mask)
India        False
France       False
England      False
Germany      False
UK           False
USA          False
Indonesia     True
Name: b, dtype: bool
```

For unique values in `list`s:

```
i = df.loc[mask, 'groupid'].unique().tolist()
print (i)
[3]

j = df.loc[~mask, 'groupid'].unique().tolist()
print (j)
[1, 4]
```

Detail:

```
print (df.groupby('groupid')['b'].transform('nunique'))
India        3
France       3
England      3
Germany      2
UK           2
USA          2
Indonesia    1
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @MartinThoma - I add solution for it.

Comment: Like the transform method :-)

Answer (score 3):

IIUC you can apply list and check for length using .str i.e

```
temp = df.groupby('groupid')['b'].apply(list).to_frame()

temp
                   b
groupid               
1            [1, 2, 3]
3                  [1]
4        [612, 612, 1]

mask = (temp['b'].str.len() == 1) & (temp['b'].str[0] == 1) 

temp[mask].index.tolist()
#[3]
temp[~mask].index.tolist()
#[1, 4]
```

Comment: This is clever :-)

Comment: Thankyou and @Jez improved this using sets which is even clever.

Comment: You can add this :-) `df.groupby('groupid')['b'].value_counts()` ,i think you know what we need.:-)

Comment: Ohk I will give a try for this one

Answer (score 1):

I would go with

```
#group by the group id and than apply count for how many b entries are equal to 1 
groups = df.groupby("groupid").apply(lambda group:len([x for x in 
group["b"].values.tolist() if x == 1]))
#keep the groups containing 1 b equal to 1 
groups = groups[groups == 1]
#print the indecies of the result (the groupid values)
print groups.index.values
```